# Finding a vector field that satisfies a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-fields, computational-mathematics

Let $f$ be a smooth function and $V$ a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$. I'm looking for an other vector field $W$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ that satisfies
$$\langle V, W \rangle + \nabla \cdot W = f$$
where $\langle,\rangle$ is the standard scalar product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\nabla \cdot W=\sum_i \partial_i W_i$ is the divergence of $W$.

I would already be very happy if I could solve this equation. More generally, I want to solve this equation for many different pairs of $(f_i,W_i)$, ideally having an (computationally not too expensive) algorithm that takes $(f,W)$ as input and produces a solution $W$.

Comment: Generally there will not be a unique solution to this equation. Indeed, by introducing an integrating factor in the usual way, we see that this PDE is formally equivalent to solving $\nabla\cdot W=\tilde{f}$ for some smooth function $\tilde{f}$. Then, adding any vector field with zero divergence will give another solution to the problem.